# What exactly does the selectnbrecv function from Golang do?

Tags: binary

I'm reverse engineering a Golang binary and came across the function `selectnbrecv`. However, I don't understand the [documentation](https://golang.org/src/runtime/chan.go?s=20089:20153#L699). I'll appreciate it if someone can explain to me the context and operation of the function. Thanks!

Comment: This might be better suited for StackOverflow.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Will ask there. Thank you!